# Exclude files/folder from VS Code editor based on CMake variant

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

For a project that I'm working on, I have four [variants](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/variants.md) (in the CMake Tools sense of the word):

- Those variants share some C files (placed in Common folder)
- Each variant has other C files which are specific
- I created Variants in cmake-variants.json file that give the buildtype different string for each variant and i could compile each variant separately.

Now i want to make it easy to browse/search through the code by excluding the specific files from each variant when one variant is selected.

I found that i can use "file.exlcude": in settings.json it works, but i can't make this variant dependent. I'm looking for a link between cmake-variant.json and settings.json.

How can this be achieved? Is it possible?

Comment: please ask a question instead of making a vague request for ideas/recommendations (see [ask]).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're looking for is supported by VS Code CMake Tools + VS Code. There's https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#variant-substitution, but to complete your ask, you'd essentially need something like CMake generator expressions inside VS Code settings value strings (which as far as I'm aware, does not exist at the time of this writing, and a past feature request failed to get enough community support to get added to the backlog: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93153 (from googling "`github vscode issues settings conditional`")).